# NHibernate: Dynamic Table Mapping

Tags: nhibernate

I have a scenario where I want to persist document info record to a table specific to the typo of document, rather than a generic table for all records.

For example, records for Invoices will be stored in dbo.Doc_1000 and records for Receipts will be stored in dbo.Doc_2000 where 1000 and 2000 are id autogenerate and store in well-known table (dbo.TypeOfDoc.

Furthermore each dbo.Doc.xxx table have a group of system column (always the same) and could have a group of dynamic column (metadata).

Tables dbo.Doc.xxx and eventually dynamic column are clearly created at runtime.

If this is possible with NHibernate???

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO that's a badly designed database... is it something legacy?

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

hope that I got your point. I am currently looking for a solution for a problem that looks similar. I want to integrate a feature in my application where the admin user can design an entity at runtime.

As far as I know, once the SessionFactory is configured and ready to use, there is no way to modify the mapping used by nhibernate. If you want to use a customized table structure that is configured, created and modified at runtime, you should have a place where a corresponding mapping lives, e.g. as a nhibernate mapping xml file and you have to set up a new SessionFactory each time you change the database model to reflect these changes.